# how to pass id value in second form of C#?

Tags: c#-3.0, desktop-application

I have two form in my C# base desktop application.

And i wants to pass my id in one form to another form.

In asp.net we use query string to pass the value for one page to second page but in C# base desktop application what i use?

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Properties or constructor arguments:

1) Properties

```
partial class Form2 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // ...
}

Form2 newForm = new Form2() { ID = id_here };
```

2) Constructor argument:

```
partial class Form2 {
    private int _id;

    public Form2(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    // ...
}

Form2 newForm = new Form2(id_here);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create public property:

On your Form1:

```
partial Class Form1()
{
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Form2 frm2 = new Form2(){passMessage="Test1"};
           frm2.Show();
           this.hide();
        }
}
```

On your Form2:

```
partial Class Form2()
{
public string passMessage;

      private void ButtonShowMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(passMessage);
        }
}
```

Regards